# Click on active and do inactive [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to click on the box, make him active and then on the second click do him inactive. I know that there is method with boolean but I'm not sure how to use it. Thank you for any help. Here's [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyfrmxon/2/).

```
$(".box").click(function(){
    var THIS = $(this);

    $(".box").removeClass("active");
    THIS.addClass("active");

});
```

Comment: [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyfrmxon/8/)

Comment: What is the question exactly, and what is the issue you're facing?

Comment: `if ($(this).hasClass("active"))...`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job. jQuery has a built in toggle function for things like this

```
$('.box').click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Need to add `$(".box").not(this).removeClass("active");` to remove active from all the other .box elements implied in OPs code.